# How do I convert a Vec<Result<T, E>> to Result<Vec<T>, E>?

Tags: rust, monads

Is there any opinionated and more elegant way to convert `Vec<Result<T, E>>` to `Result<Vec<T>, E>`? I want to get `Ok<Vec<T>>` if all values of vector are `Ok<T>` and `Err<E>` if at least one is `Err<E>`.

Example:

```
fn vec_of_result_to_result_of_vec<T, E>(v: Vec<Result<T, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
    E: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let mut new: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

    for el in v.into_iter() {
        if el.is_ok() {
            new.push(el.unwrap());
        } else {
            return Err(el.unwrap_err());
        }
    }

    Ok(new)
}
```

I'm looking for a more declarative way to write this. This function forces me to write a `where` clause which will never be used and `Err(el.unwrap_err())` looks useless. In other words, the code does many things just to make the compiler happy. I feel like this is such a common case that there's a better way to do it.

Comment: You can avoid the `unwrap()`s (and the `Debug` bounds) by using a `match` instead of `is_ok()`.  But in this case `collect()` is even cleaner.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

An iterator over `Result<T, E>` can be `collect()`-ed directly into a `Result<Vec<T>, E>`; that is, your entire function can be replaced with:

```
let new: Result<Vec<T>, E> = v.into_iter().collect()
```

Comment: could you explain this behavior? I dont know why collecting an Iterator would remove the  Result structure type from its content

Comment: @Tobi the `collect` method on an iterator (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) works for any type that implements the trait `FromIterator`. As stated by @chpio, there is an implementation of `FromIterator` for iterators of `Result`.

Comment: The `collect` method here is rather flexible.  `v.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()` return a vector of results.  `v.into_iter().collect::<Result<Vec<_>,_>>()` returns a result of vector.  And presumably if the compiler can figure out which one you want, you don't need the turbo fish.

Comment: What happens to the right-hand side of the Result though? Presumably the first Error that is encountered is returned (kind of like a short-circuit)? This seems similar to traversal in functional libraries like cats in Scala, but I believe the Errors would be collected together by `folding` them into one another in cats.

Comment: @Oli That's right. If the iterator yields an `Err`, then iteration stops and the error is returned.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`FromIterator` trait implementation on `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA,+E%3E%3E-for-Result%3CV,+E%3E) ([`.collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) requires `FromIterator` on the destination type and calls into it for the conversion from `Iterator`):

```rust
fn vec_of_result_to_result_of_vec<T, E>(v: Vec<Result<T, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    v.into_iter().collect()
}
```